# Kotlin tests with coveragge in intelij failed assertions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, junit

I have problem with intelij and coverage tests, when im running unit tests, without coverage, just by normally intelij run tests, all tests are success, but when i try to run it by tests with coverage, all tests assertions are failed, probably its problem with kotlin object keyword, because when i change test class from object to class, coverage tests runs successfully, any body have idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide an example of test that you have ?

Comment: I can not show the code, but its unit tests using mockk librarary

Comment: Do you use static mocks (e.g. `mockkStatic`) that are not unmockked?
Had a similar problem. Locally the test would run successfully and on Jenkins they failed.

Comment: i used mockObject, but fianaly decide change the object to class, it solve problem, probably intelij coveragge not working good with kotiln objects